# Android Mediaplayer Error(-19, 0) doesn't work with release()

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I try to replay a sound 30 times with delay, but I get the **Error (-19, 0)** even I had add **release().**
Besides, my **TextView** doesn't change until the final sound.

My code:

```
 protected void playbtn(View view) {

    TextView t2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    for(int i=0; i<30; i++){

        try {
            //delay
            Thread.sleep(2000);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        t2.setText("music :"+i);
        System.out.println(i+" now\n");

        MediaPlayer mp= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music1);
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();
            };
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that you can play 30 sounds simultaneously. Why you need such a noise?

Comment: I want to play 30 sounds continuously , not simultaneously.

Comment: then you don't need to do it in cycle. you need to start another sound when previous is finished.

Comment: You mean that I have to copy this code for 30 times?

Comment: no, to create a method which will play next sound, and call it in the `OnCompletionListener`

Comment: It works. Thank you so much!!